# adding text to a each page of a pdf using Itext

Tags: java, pdf, itext

how to add a paragraph to each page using `itext`without using `ColumnText.showTextAligned` because the text added to each page is different and can span multiple lines.
is it possible to add text using `PdfStamper` ? Or should i use `PdfWriter` . i prefer using `PdfStamper` to get this done because `PdfStamper` was already used to add annotations and this functionality can be integrated easily.

Answer (score 1):

You can add paragraphs straight into the document object
(http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-itext/paragraph.html)

Or I have personally used a PdfTable with 100% width. It easily lines up all the paragraph objects (http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=76)

Both of those methods support either formatted text or a plain string which will instead use defaults.

You can do it with a stamper, but it requires the ColumnText.showTextAligned method.

Comment: i tried using ColumnText.showTextAligned method.The string had several sentences seperated by a \n. Just the first sentence was added. and how do i specify the page number? i mean which page the text is to be added to?

Comment: That is used to post straight text to a location. A paragraph object is formatted with multiple lines and will insert newlines and such. iText works on a page by page basis. So when you're inserting the data for each page include the text then.  ie Document doc = new Document(...) , doc.add(para1) , doc.newpage() ,doc.add(para2) 

Are you copying over a bunch of pages from an existing PDF and you're adding text to some? Or just making a new pdf that needs multiple lines of text on each page?

Comment: The static method `showTextAligned()` can only draw one line at a time. If you want to add `Paragraph`s, then you need to create a `ColumnText` instance, define a `Rectangle`, add `Element`s and use the `go()` method.

Comment: and what if my document has more than one page? and paragraph to be added to each page is different?